# wcf - multiple KnowType commands - proper pattern for execution

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I have a WCF service used to execute some commands from clients.
I have a base class, **AbstractCommand** and a number of derived classes which define concrete commands.

The WCF web service has a single method **void Execute(AbstractCommand command)**. It can accept concrete commands (classes derived from AbstractCommand) by means of the **[KnownType]** attribute. The commands are executed against a database via a **Repository**.

To simplify, let's say that commands are executed in the service something like this:

```
public void Excecute(AbstractCommand command) {
   // Concrete command 1
   var theCommand = command as ConcreteCommand1;
   if (theCommand != null) {
      var par1 = theCommand.Par1;
      var par2 = theCommand.Par2;
      ...
      _repository.DoSomething(par1, par2...);
      return;
   }
   // Concrete command 2
   var theCommand = command as ConcreteCommand2;
      ...
```

This if-branching looks a little bit scary and I want to refactor it.
I'm thinking about something like this: The **AbstractCommand** should define and **ConcreteCommand**s should implement a method **Execute** which will look like this:

```
public class ConcreteCommand1 : AbstractCommand {
   public int Par1 { get; set; }
   public int Par2 { get; set; }
   ...

   public void Execure(IRepository repository) {
      repository.DoSomething(Par1, Par2...);
```

so that in the service I no longer need to have that nasty if-branching and can do just this:

```
public void Excecute(AbstractCommand command) {
   command.Execure(_repository);
}
```

It looks fine. The only drawback with this approach is that now **ConcreteCommand** classes instead of just being DTOs (par1, par2...) need to define logic in them (the Execute method) and should be aware about the **IRepository**.

Can anybody suggest a better approach?

Comment: I think your approach makes sense and is pretty close to a command pattern (http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern). If is possible, try to inject the repository by constructor instead than by method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented the solution in the way I described above - it is quite flexible and extensible.
If there are any suggestions for improvements - please welcome.